Kusto Query Exclude the Range Values with Dynamic Data type
We need to exclude the given range values under dynamic data types. We need to do this for Integer, Double and DateTime. All these values are stored in dynamic data type with dictionary model. Also for this we have given sample data for each data type to understand the requirement clearly.
For example we have below sample data.


DateTime :- {"A": "2024-08-12T02:33:33.6740000Z","B": "2024-08-12T02:39:33.6740000Z",   "C": "2024-08-12T02:44:33.6740000Z"
},
{"A": "2024-08-13T02:33:33.6740000Z","B": "2024-08-13T02:39:33.6740000Z",   "C": "2024-08-13T02:44:33.6740000Z"
},
{"A": "2024-08-14T02:33:33.6740000Z","B": "2024-08-14T02:39:33.6740000Z",   "C": "2024-08-14T02:44:33.6740000Z"
}
If we EXCEPT these Range value (Start:  2024-08-12 02:33:33.6740000 End:  2024-08-13T02:44:33.6740000Z) We need to exclude(First row and Second Row Which fall under these given range in Datetime) whole set of data which contains the Range Start and End value. In other words we need to exclude first row, second row and return third row only.


Integer:- { "A": 2001,  "B": 2002,  "C": 2001,  "D": 2004,
    "E": 2005}
{   "A": 1000,  "B": 1002,  "C": 1001,  "D": 1004,  "E": 1005},
{   "A": 3000,  "B": 3002,  "C": 3001,  "D": 3004,  "E": 3005}


If we EXCEPT the Range value (Start : "2001" and End: "2005") We need to exclude whole set of data(First row in integer) which contains the given range value. In other words we need to exclude first row and return second row, third row only.

Double { "T1": 10.297,  "T2": -30.76217,    "T3": 9.3046781,"T4": 1.3959,   "T5": -5.2594 },
{   "T1": 1.297,    "T2": -1.76217,     "T3": 0.3046781,    "T4": 1.3959, 
    "T5": -2.2594
},
{   "T1": 11.297,   "T2": -12.76217,    "T3": 13.3046781,   "T4": 14.3959, 
    "T5": -2.2594
},
If we EXCEPT the range value (start: "10.297" and End : "12.00") We need to exclude whole set of data(First row and Third row in double) which falls under given range values. In other words we need to exclude first row and third row and return second row only.

Please help in this regard.

Note:- All are dynamic data types.

All key values are string and values are corresponding to given datatypes as datetime, integer and double.

Thanks in advance

If you know the column names, you can try the below code to achieve your requirement.
This code first creates table from the given JSON. After creating table, pack all the columns as an array column and check whether each value is in the given range or not. Here, you need to give your column names. Use mv-apply and create a flag column which will have the value count of the number of values from each row which satisfies the given condition. Then, check whether this value is equal to the length of the array column or not. If this value is same as length of array column, it means all the values in that row are satisfying the condition. Otherwise, they will be avoided.
Here is a sample for the integer data type:
let result = 
print myDynamicValue = dynamic(
[
    {"A": 2001,"B": 2002,"C": 2001,"D": 2004,"E": 2005},
    {"A": 1000,"B": 1002,"C": 1001,"D": 1004,"E": 1005},
    {"A": 3000,"B": 3002,"C": 3001,"D": 3004,"E": 3005}
]) 
| mvexpand myDynamicValue 
| evaluate bag_unpack(myDynamicValue);

result
| extend com_arr=pack_array(A,B,C,D,E)
| mv-apply Value = com_arr on (
    summarize flag = countif(not(Value > 2001 and Value < 2005))
)
| where flag == array_length(com_arr)
| project-away com_arr,flag;

Result:

You can modify this code as per the remaining data types.

Thanks Rakesh Govindula for your example and explanation.  Will try your approach.
